# rrule.js UNTIL is miscalculated when DTSTART has timezone (TZID)

Tags: javascript, calendar, icalendar, rrule

ive found a weird behaviour in rrule.js which seems like a bug. but i couldnt find any complains about it. so im tryiing my luck here. maybe someone can share some wisdom...

**description**
When DTSTART has timezone (TZID), and UNTIL is in UTC time (how it should be following in the spec). the library mistakenly regarding it as in local time. which leads to wrong events output

**example**
using this RRULE
`RRule.fromString('DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Jerusalem:20230805T123000\nRRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20230819T093000Z').all()`
ends up with only 2 events:

2023-08-05T12:30:00.000Z
2023-08-12T12:30:00.000Z
when it should render one more event (2023-08-19T12:30:00.000Z)

**specification**
If the "DTSTART" property is specified as a date with UTC time or a date with local time and time zone reference, then the UNTIL rule part MUST be specified as a date with UTC time.

**a live example**
https://codesandbox.io/embed/rrule-forked-39whj8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

origin python lib is behaving correctly and resulting with the correct events. please see the following example
https://www.online-python.com/TY1pxQZaGr

using version 2.7.2,
macOS 13.4.1 (c)
local timezone: Israel Daylight Time

Thanks
Zach